# How to find the element that is most on top of all visible elements? (Nearest to user)

Tags: javascript, html, z-index

If we assume the desktop is a real desktop, I would like to find the paper, that is on top of all the others, nearest to the user's nose.

I know I have read somewhere, there would be a relativly new (may be years) javascript command, to let the browser do the work, but I can't find the reference anymore.

[ <strike>Edit: I remember there was a *3-D view* of html-pages in former Firefox versions' developer tools. (It was removed, as far as I can remember.) That tool must contain an algorythm for determining the effective order of elements.</strike>    Just checked the screenshots of Firefox former 3-D view tool, and it doesn't seem to really look for the nearest element, but just doing a simple stack up. Seems to be a dead end. ]

Comment: You mean the element that has the highest z-index?

Comment: `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` will return the 'nearest' element at the x/y coordinates you pass in. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint
Looking at the highest z-index doesn't necessarily give you an element that is rendered on top of everything else since it depends on the rendering order of its ancestors.

Comment: @Lennholm That's indeed the function I was looking for. Though I see now it's not working for my case, with z-indexed elements nested and freely positioned on the desktop.

Comment: Two upvotes for this??

Answer (score 1):

You can create `getHighestZindex` function that is defined like below:

```
function getHighestZindex(elem)
{
  const elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
  let top = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
  {
    const zindex = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elems[i],null).getPropertyValue("z-index");
    if ((zindex > top) && (zindex != 'auto'))
    {
      top = zindex;
    }
  }
  return top;
}
```

You can call `getHighestZIndex` for a particular element type such as a 'DIV' like this:

```
getHighestZIndex('div');
```

#### EDIT

There will be two use cases to check which element is on top

- If none of the elements have `z-index` defined in css
- If any element or all elements have specific `z-index` defined in css.

So there will be a check `has_allauto` added in the function...

Let's say you have `html` code like below:

```html
<div id="block-1">
 <div id="inner-block"></div>
</div>
<div id="block-2"></div>
```

and to check which element is on top view, the function will be like below:

```js
function getHighestZindex(elem) {
  const elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
  let id = "";
  let top = 0;
  let has_allauto = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    const zindex = document.defaultView
      .getComputedStyle(elems[i], null)
      .getPropertyValue("z-index");

    if (zindex !== "auto") {
      has_allauto = false;
    }

    if (zindex > top && zindex != "auto") {
      top = zindex;
      id = elems[i].id;
    }
  }
  if(has_allauto) {
    id = elems[elems.length-1].id;
  }
  return id;
}
```

This will return `id` of the element which is on top of the view.

Working example [Example](https://codepen.io/HarishSha/pen/MWKXmQR)

Comment: Does this include elements that do not have `z-index` specified? The OP makes no mention of using z-index.

Comment: Each element has their own default z-index. So the answer is `yes` we can include elements which don't have z-index added in CSS

Comment: There's no guarantee that the element with the highest z-index is the one that is rendered on top of all other elements. If this element is a descendant of an element that itself has a lower z-index than its own siblings, there may be some other element rendered on top. To always find the element actually rendered on top you'd need to make some kind of recursive function that tracks how the elements are nested.

Comment: @Lennholm That's a great point you mentioned here. I'm trying to replicate the same via working example.

Comment: I created an example with slight code change. It works in both cases.. https://codepen.io/HarishSha/pen/MWKXmQR

Answer (score 1):

If you want the grab the element on top, you can reduce the elements by checking their current z-index and storing the highest one as you loop through them.

Once you are done, just return the reference with the highest index.

```js
const computeHigestElement = (elementsOrSelector) => {
  const elements = typeof elementsOrSelector === 'string'
    ? document.querySelectorAll(elementsOrSelector) : elementsOrSelector
  return [...elements].reduce((higest, el, index) => {
    const zIndex = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null)
      .getPropertyValue('z-index');
    return !isNaN(zIndex) && parseInt(zIndex, 10) > higest.index
      ? Object.assign(higest, { ref: el, index: parseInt(zIndex, 10) })
      : higest
  }, { ref: null, index: -1 }).ref // <-- Return the highest element
}

console.log(`Top element: ${computeHigestElement('.card').textContent}`)
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 180px;
  border: thin solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 180px;
}

.card:nth-child(1) {
  background: green;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
  top: 25px;
  left: 100px;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="z-index:50">Middle</div>
<div class="card" style="z-index:100">Top</div>
<div class="card" style="z-index:auto">Bottom</div>
```